# How to extract sub element href using beautifulsoup python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is my html code

```
<div class="search_col_2">

                <h2><a href="/profile.php?id=2323232">Maahsuj akisak</a><span class="for-complete-profile">  </span>
                </h2>

<div class="search_col_2">
                <h2><a href="/profile.php?id=23232">Nunapu akisak</a><span class="for-complete-profile">  </span>
                </h2>
<div class="search_col_2">
                <h2><a href="/profile.php?id=2323332">Rahenu Kahiske</a><span class="for-complete-profile">  </span>
                </h2>
```

I want to extract href values from it

so far i've tried this but doesnt work

```
soupeddata = BeautifulSoup(my_html_code, "html.parser")
my_data = soupeddata.find_all("div", class_= "search_col_2")
for x in my_data:
    my_href = x.get("href")
    print(my_href)
```

i need to extract hrefs inside div class "search_col_2" , i dont want to extract any other links and there are other links which are under  but i dont need them.

Comment: Why are you searching for `div`s if you want to extract the `href` values? You should be searching for `a` tags...

Comment: because i need to extract hrefs inside div class "search_col_2" , i dont want to extract any other links and there are other links which are under <a> but i dont need them

Comment: That's an important piece of information that should be [edit]ed into the question.

Comment: The `div` tags are not closing here. Is that a typo? If not, you've to add all the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the `div` tags are not closing, you'll get the required output using the following code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = [x.find('a')['href'] for x in soup.find_all('div', class_= "search_col_2")]
print(links)
# ['/profile.php?id=2323232', '/profile.php?id=23232', '/profile.php?id=2323332']
```

**Explanation:**

You have all the `div` tags in the `my_data` variable. The `div` tags don't have a `href` attribute. So, using `.get('href')` on any `div` will return `None`. You will have to find the `a` tags inside the `div` tags using `.find('a')` and then get the `href` attribute as shown in the above code.

Comment: This works if you dont mind can you please explain what was my mistake ? and can you please explain your code ? if you dont mind otherwise its okay and thanks :)

Comment: Added some explanation. If you've any more doubts, feel free to ask. Also, if you're not familiar with *list comprehensions*, just Google it (I've used it in my code).

Comment: Okay thanks and you've explained very well thank you so much for it i've got one question why did you use lxml instead of html.parser ? it isnt possible to do it using html.parser ?

Comment: Both are html parsers, and both will do the same thing. You can use any one of them. Lxml is just a bit faster than html.parser. [Have a look at the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).